# loading scene overlap 2d from libgdx since new update

Tags: java, libgdx, desktop, overlap2d

So i created a scene with Overlap2D then tryed to load it from my LibGdx application.

LibGdx 1.5.4
Overlap2D 007

I followed this tutoriel -> https://github.com/azakhary/Overlap2DSheepDemo
But it seem to use an old version of Overlap2D.

The problem come from my Asset manager. In the tutorial he use IRessource interface but with my Overlap2D  version i just have :
IResourceRetriever and IResourceLoader

I don't understand how to load and use my generated project 
If someone got the previous Overlap 2D version i'm interested too

Comment: This question is better suited for the Overlap2D forum. Azakhary him self will help you.

Answer (score 2):

sorry about that. Things changed, I have made a new video that will explain how to make this all work:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=618&v=0Qmkfw2svs0